# Error 262145 while trying to insert in SQL db with TwinCat 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, plc, twincat

I am trying to insert data into a SQL Server database from TwinCat 2 program. When the trigger is activated, I am getting the following error: 262145

[image: Error codes]

```
racer_name : STRING(256);
racer_name := 'CS1';

FB_FormatStringC1_lap_db(
    sFormat:='INSERT INTO demo VALUES (%S, %D, %D)',
    arg1:= F_STRING(racer_name),
    arg2:= F_DWORD(C1_Lap_Minutes),
    arg3:= F_DWORD(C1_Lap_Seconds),
    bError=> ,
    nErrId=> ,
    sOut=>sInsertStringC1_lap_db );


FB_DBRecordInsertC1_lap_db(
    sNetID:= ,
    hDBID:=1 ,
    sInsertCmd:=sInsertStringC1_lap_db ,
    bExecute:=  dummy,
    tTimeout:=T#30s ,
    bBusy=> bBusyInsert,
    bError=> bErrInsert,
    nErrID=> nErridInsert,
    sSQLState=> );
```

[image: Db design]

The communication to the server is running, because i tried to import only integers and it's working without any problem.

Maybe I am not formatting the string variables properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, post the actual and complete error message - including the number, text, state, etc. within your post as text. Posting images is highly discouraged for many reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO demo VALUES (%S, %D, %D)
```

You are giving 3 columns for insert while your table has 4. Assuming that `id` is autogenerated, you can *explictly* not provide it by enumerating the target columns:

```
INSERT INTO demo (racer, minuteslap, secondslap) VALUES (%S, %D, %D)
```

This is one of the reasons why always enumerating the target columns in a `insert` statement is a best practice.